# Choose/2 multiple answers swi prolog

Tags: prolog, infinite

how can I define a choose/2 to give infinite answers

```
  choose(List, Elt) :-
    length(List, Length),
    random(0, Length, Rand),
    nth1(Rand, List, Elt).
```

my choose/2 gives only one answer

examples:

```
?- choose([1,2,3],Elt).
Elt = 1;
Elt = 1;
Elt = 3;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Append as the second clause

```
choose(List, E) :- choose(List, E).
```

to your program. By the way, you seem to want nth0/3 instead of nth1/3. And a better, more declarative name instead of "choose/2" is for example "list_choice/2".

Answer (score 2):

Try using repeat:

`choose(L, O) :- repeat, member(O, L).`

it will backtrack through all the members of list, then repeat will cause it to try all those members again.

`?- choose([1,2,3],Out).
Out = 1 ; 
Out = 2 ; 
Out = 3 ;
Out = 1 ;
Out = 2 ;
Out = 3 ;`